# How to split a dataframe into a list keeping the previous dataframe in R?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, split

I have this data frame

This is a minimal reproducible example of my data frame

```
value <- c(rnorm(39, 5, 2))
Date <- seq(as.POSIXct('2021-01-18'), as.POSIXct('2021-10-15'), by = "7 days")

df <- data.frame(Date, value)

# This is the vector I have to compare with the Date of the dataframe
dates_tour <- as.POSIXct(c('2021-01-18', '2021-05-18', '2021-08-18', '2021-10-15'))

df <- df %>%
  mutate(
    tour = cut(Date, breaks = dates_tour, labels = seq_along(dates_tour[-1]))
  )
```

Now that I have the data frame label on each group based on the `dates_tour` I want to split the data frame based on the `tour` factor but I need that each list contains the data frame of the previous data frame.
For instance `df_list[[1]]` contains the rows with `tour == 1`The second list needs to contain the first and the second data frame `tour == 1 | tour == 2`. The third list needs to contain the first, second, and third data frames and so on. I need to work writing a general code that works with different lengths of `dates_tour` as sometimes it can contain different lengths of values.

This code creates a list based on the `tour` value

```
df_list = split(df, df$tour)
```

But is not useful to create what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do:

```
Reduce(rbind, split(df, ~tour), accumulate = TRUE)
```

if you have an older version of R:

```
Reduce(rbind, split(df, df$tour), accumulate = TRUE)
```

You could also use `accumulate` from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
accumulate(split(df, ~tour), rbind)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use a loop for that

```
df_list <- lapply(unique(df$tour), function(x) subset(df, tour %in% seq_len(x)))
```